# Update one panel using another panel but return the rendered content of changed panel only

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I just got a form in modal popup extender and It want it to work like below,

1.`Submit, Cancel` buttons to close the modal popup are inside `updatepanel1`

2.There is a `label` inside the TargetControlPanel `Panel1` which is inside `updatepanel2`

3.The Submit works async as it is inside the `updatepanel1`, exactly as i wanted it to. Also Displaying the result of submit in `label` too works as expected. BUT, i want the response to return only the rendered result of `updatepanel2`, actually the rendereded result of the both `updatepanel1` and `updatepanel2` are returned.

I just got a load of event handlers on the cancel button which are getting replaced due to the update from updatepanel1` and i don't use jQuery. So adding event handlers is what i don't want to do again. and thats why this question popped up.

Comment: On `updatepanel1`, is [ChildrenAsTriggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.childrenastriggers.aspx) set to true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL How stupid, i could have thought about `this 5 minutes more` to get the answer.

Here is what i did:

```
<modal popup extender></modal popup extender>
<target Button></target button>
<target panel>
<blah blah blah/>
<updatepanel>
<label result>
</updatepanel>
<blah blah blah/>
<updatepanel2>
<button submit/>
</updatepanel2>
<button Cancel>
</target panel>
```

That's a Pseudocode , by putting the **cancel button outside** the updatepanel i had nothing to lose there sweet